# Can I use Mist only as a wallet for a blockchain node in another machine?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, mist, nodes

I have a Mist wallet on Machine 1 and a private Geth node running a blockchain on Machine 2. Is it possible for me to submit a transaction from Machine 1 to the blockchain on Machine 2?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can work, but you'll have to connect Mist on M1 via JSON RPC to M2.

1. open the JSON RPC port on M2 where your node is running (relevant parameters are `--rpc` and `--rpcapi` (see https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC)
2. start Mist from the command line with `--rpc http://M2:8545`

Note that you'll have to protect the access to your JSON RPC port on M2. Otherweise, everyone with access to this machine will be able to call exposed APIs.